# Background image repositioning

Tags: html, css

An image that I'm using for the background of a website is getting positioned to just the center of the page.

The screenshot for what I'm explaining is as follows:

[image: Background image]

Why is the black space on the right and left of the image present?

The CSS for the following is:

```
body {
background: black url('http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/johnny-lam-connect.jpg')no-repeat 50% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that your background image isn't big enough to cover the space of your window size. As a result, the `black` background color you're also providing is being seen on the areas where your image can't cover.

I'd be tempted to try the following:

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/johnny-lam-connect.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will ensure your background image covers the `body` of your HTML. More info [can be found here](http://www.css3files.com/background/).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is black because in your CSS you specify black as the background colour. But im assuming you mean why is there any blank space at all...

In which case, the simple answer is the size of your image does not match the size of the window. More specifically, the resolution and therefore width to height ratio is not the same as the window. So the browser will center the image as per your css instructions and fill the rest of the space with your solid base colour (black).

You basically have 3 options here.

1. You find a background colour that is appropriate for the blank space to fit in with your design (a lot of people add a border or fade the image edges to transparent so it looks purposeful).
2. You use an image which is repeatable (this is the most common step as its usually advisable to use a very small repeatable image rather than a single large image. As an example, you might have a 2000px image gradient going from one colour to another that can be repeated (aka tiled) horizontally.
3. Use the `background-size: cover` property to fore the background image to fully cover your body tag. This property can be set to a number of options, but each one comes with its own caveats (i.e. weird stretching issues or cropping important parts on certain screens). So you need to google for the valid values and test each one. You will also have to download a shim/polyfill for this property to support old browsers (IE?).

Comment: Yes, I did mean the blank space. I knew that that I had already specified black...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the body is used to center the page. As the body is just as wide as the content, thats where the image ends. The root `html` element gets the background-color from the body, but not the image.

As a solution, you should consider adding a wrapping div to center the page, while setting the background on the body.

Example HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="page"> ... </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: black url(...) no-repeat center top;
}

.page {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css use following property:

```
body {
background-size:cover;
}
```

or

```
body {
background-size:100%(for width) 100%(for height);
}
```

Hope it will help.